# How to check if tweet is retweeted?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

Hi I am using tmhoauth and php. need to know how to check if certain user(id) retweeted certain tweet(id)?
I found GET statuses/retweeters/ids but how to use it in php to confirm?

Answer (score 0):

tmhOauth has a sample github repository that can help you to inspire on how to do the request you need:

https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuthExamples/tree/master/web

For example, here's the [search/tweets](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuthExamples/blob/master/web/search_tweets.php) request:

```
$code = $tmhOAuth->apponly_request(array(
  'url' => $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/search/tweets'),
  'params' => array(
    'q' => $_GET['q']
  )
));
```

In the case of GET statuses/retweeters/ids, you should adapt to something like this:

```
$code = $tmhOAuth->user_request(array(
  'url' => $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/retweets/509457288717819904.json'),
));

if ($code == 200) :
  $data = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response'], true);
}
```

Comment: this lloks to me like only checking if tweet have retweets!?